# converting the jdbc query into JPA native query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Below is the code that is been wriiten by using jdbc , now i want to only convert it into native query of JPA   , please let me
know how i can change the below method code which is using jdbc into native query equivqlent , any help wuld be much appreciated ,
this method is just only inserting the data into the database , I have intialised the entity manger of JPA

```
public void insertATMLog(ATMLogRow ATMlLogRow)
    conn = getConnection();
           String sQuery = "insert into CTL_LOG " +
                            "( " +
                              " CTL_LOG_ID, " +
                              " HOME_ID, " +
                              " PERSON_ID, " +
                              " FROM_ADDRESS, " +
                              " TO_ADDRESS, " +
                              " SUBJECT, " +
                              " BODY, " +
                              " STATUS, " +
                              " SENT_DATE, " +
                              " CC_ADDRESS, " +
                              " BCC_ADDRESS, " +
                              " REPLY_TO, " +
                              " CUSTOMER_INSTITUTION_ID, " +
                              " EFT_TRANSACTION_ID " +
                              " , PARTNER_EMAIL_ADDRESS , CREATED_ON , FROM_ADDRESS_ALIAS, DELIVERY_CHANNEL" +
                              ")" +
                              " values (CTL_LOG_seq.nextval,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,sysdate,?,?,?,?,?,?,systimestamp,?,?)";
           pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sQuery);

           pstmt.setInt(1,ATMlLogRow.homeID);
           pstmt.setInt(2,ATMlLogRow.personID);
           pstmt.setString(3,ATMlLogRow.fromAddress);
           pstmt.setString(4,ATMlLogRow.toAddress);
           pstmt.setString(5,ATMlLogRow.subject);
            PCUtils.setClobColumn(pstmt,6,ATMlLogRow.body);
             pstmt.setInt(7, status);
             pstmt.setString(8,ATMlLogRow.ccAddress);
           pstmt.setString(9,ATMlLogRow.bccAddress);
           pstmt.setString(10,ATMlLogRow.replyTo);
           if (ATMlLogRow.cfiID > 2)
                pstmt.setInt(11, ATMlLogRow.cfiID);
           else
                pstmt.setNull(11, Types.INTEGER);
           if (ATMlLogRow.eftTransactionID > 3)
                pstmt.setInt(12, ATMlLogRow.eftTransactionID);
           else
                pstmt.setNull(12, Types.INTEGER);
              pstmt.setString(13, ATMlLogRow.partnerEmailAddress);
                   pstmt.setString(14, ATMlLogRow.fromAddressEmailAlias);
           pstmt.setString(15, ATMlLogRow.deliveryChannel);
                       int count = pstmt.executeUpdate();
```

Comment: Do an internet search for JPA, and how to use it; there are lots of documents out there. This site is not to convert things for you

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are asking for the very basics of what JPA is.

First you need to create a POJO class annotated with `@Entity`.

Then you just set the fields according to your logic.

Lastly simply call `entityManager.persist`.